# Getting "Sorry, please enter the key" on PHP cUrl request

Tags: php

I am following the **API Redeem Microsoft** call from this website: [https://getcid.info/developers]](https://getcid.info/developers%5D)

Here is my PHP code for the cURL request:

```
$url = 'https://getcid.info/api-key-digital';
 
$curl = curl_init();

$fields = [
    'key' => '1231232-1232123-1232123-1231232-5762636-1232123-1232123-1232123-1232123'
];

$fields_string = http_build_query($fields);
 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
 
$data = curl_exec($curl);

echo '<pre>';
     var_dump( $data );
echo '</pre>';
 
curl_close($curl);
```

**But I am getting an error message;**

> {"status":"error","res":"Sorry, please enter the key"}

I don't understand why this error message is showing as I have passed the key!

Comment: The remote side seems to think you didn't.

Comment: The documentation shows JSON requests, you are not sending JSON.

Comment: @CBroe let me try with JSON.

Comment: @CBroe Now, I am using this: https://codeshare.io/Wd4QBy but the same error message. Do you know why?

Comment: The examples are sending an _array_ of objects, you are sending just a single plain object. You need `$fields = [ [ 'key' => '...' ] ];`

Comment: Can you check the code again: https://codeshare.io/Wd4QBy as I am getting same message?

Comment: It appears to work fine if I send the JSON data from the example, so I am guessing your format is off. The keys they are using there are all 29 characters long, yours is 71?

Comment: Can you send me your example code to me, Please?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/eL7YpwxL

Comment: @Shibbir the key format given in API is : `[
  {"key":"XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"},
  {"key":"XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX"}
]` try to pass like that

Comment: @CBroe you are correct. I have passed wrong length key.

Comment: @Shibbir  since this question is solved in comments and is syntax error issue. So kindly delete the question.